# mongoose .save() not going into .save() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I am facing problems with mongoose .save() function.

Index.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var companySchema = rootRequire('models/company');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');


var company = new companySchema({activate: false, company_code: '123', name: 'A123' });
console.log(company);
company.save(function(err){
    if(err){
    console.log("now it can be associated with db",err);    
    }
    else{
        console.log("bingo");
    }
});
```

My console log output is

> { activate: false,   _id: 582997952a3134cc08672607,   name: 'A123',
>   company_code: '123' }

I did't received any of log

> console.log("now it can be associated with db",err);

or

> console.log("bingo");

My company.js looks like

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var companySchema = new Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        sparse: true,
        unique: true
    },
    company_code: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    activate: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    logo: {
        type: String
    }

}, {
    collection: 'company'
});


var Company = mongoose.model('company',companySchema)

module.exports = Company;
```

Comment: what's `rootRequire`look like?

Comment: DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated,

Comment: @Qop var rootRequire = require('root-require');
Package of npm

Comment: have you tried using `var companySchema = mongoose.model('company')` instead of `var companySchema = rootRequire('models/company');`?

Comment: @Qop Thanks I've made common file for schema design and api and it found working. But it didn't solved my problem. How to include it in another file?

Comment: You don't need them in a single file, you can import `mongoose.model('company')`wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Working with a single file solved my problem but not feasible option.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Company Schema
var companySchema = new Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        sparse: true,
        unique: true
    },
    company_code: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    activate: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    logo: {
        type: String
    }

}, {
    collection: 'company'
});


var Company = mongoose.model('company',companySchema)
//console.log(Company);


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
var company = new Company({activate: false, company_code: '123', name: 'OSPL3' });

console.log(company);
company.save(function(err){
    console.log('comses');
    if(err){
    console.log("now it can be associated with db",err);    
    }
    else{
        console.log("bingo");
    }
});
```

Weather my problem associated with rootRequire?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code to execute and I've just added one line 
var rootRequire = require('root-require'); 
into index.js and it works fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose should included before schema design.

If you'll look at my previous answer and code it will be more clear